# Il y a une difference d'intensité entre pénible, chiant, embêter, s'énerver, déranger?

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai utilisé tous les verbes/adjectifs dans le titre plusieurs fois, mais quand j'y réfléchis, je ne suis pas sûr qu'il y ait une différence bien définie entre eux. Voici des exemples où je pense que je pourrais utiliser chacun :

- Arrête, t'es **pénible**, hein! (pas de contexte, mais imagine que tu te
  bats contre ton petit frère dans sa chambre ou quelque chose comme
  ça)
- Je déteste quand ces motos passent vers la maison avec tout ce bruit. C'est trop **chiant**.
- Oups, désolé pour le bruit, je n'ai pas remarqué que tu lisais. Je ne veux pas **t'embêter**.
- Est-ce que ça **te dérange** si je laisse mes affaires ici sur la table?
- Ugh, regarde en face, c'est un grand embouteillage, **ça m'énerve**.

Aussi, dites-moi si j'ai tort à propos de mes exemples ci-dessus.

Comment: Sur les autres sites, on n'est pas censé demander des revisions. Ici, je ne sais pas....

Comment: @Lambie Désolé si j'ai mal compris votre commentaire, mais je n'ai pas demandé des revisions. Il y a rien à corriger, j'ai juste donné des exemples pour mieux illustrer ma question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il peut y avoir une différence d'intensité, mais il y a surtout une différence de registre:

- **ennuyeux** / **ennuyer**: registre neutre ou poli, peut véhiculer de la réprobation ("tu es ennuyeux", "le bruit est ennuyeux"), mais aussi de l'inquiétude ou de la compassion ("la situation est ennuyeuse")
- **dérangeant** / **déranger**: registre neutre, peut désigner une attitude volontaire ou involontaire sans réprobation ("excuse-moi, tu me déranges, je suis au téléphone")
- **pénible**: registre neutre, avec de la réprobation ("tu es pénible, tu m'as encore dérangé")
- **agaçant** / **agacer**: registre neutre, sens similaire
- **énervant** / **énerver**: registre neutre tirant sur le familier dans cet usage (le sens littéraire est un peu différent du sens courant), avec plus d'intensité et de colère ("il s'est énervé" = "il s'est mis en colère")
- **embêtant** / **embêter**: registre familier, parfois employé comme euphémisme pour les suivants
- **chiant** / **faire chier**: registre vulgaire, employé si couramment que le sens est assez atténué
- **emmerdant** / **emmerder**: registre vulgaire, avec plus d'intensité et de colère

Comment: Merci! C'est ce que je cherchais.

Comment: J'en ai ajouté deux que j'avais oubliés: "agaçant / agacer" et "énervant / énerver".

Answer (score 2):

> Arrêtes, t'es pénible, hein! (pas de context, mais imagine tu bats contre ton petit frère dans son chambre ou quelque chose comme ça)

Cela me semble correct

> Je déteste quand ces motos passent par la maison avec tout ce bruit. C'est trop chiant.

ou vous pourriez aussi dire que c'est ennuyeux  ou fatigant.

> Oups, désolé pour le bruit, je n'ai pas remarqué que tu lisais. Je ne veux pas t'embêter.

On pourrait utiliser déranger ici. Quand je pense embêter je pense ennuyeux ou taquiner.

> Est-ce que ça te dérange si je laisse mes affaires ici sur la table?

Cela me semble correct

> Ugh, regarde en face, c'est un grand embouteillage, ça m'énerve.

oui, énervé ou bouleversé

Comment: Merci pour le réponse - c'est utile!

Comment: Je vous en prie.  :)